# Ignore part string and distinct

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that looks something like this:

```
SELECT paginas_acesso.id, tipo_acesso, tipos_acesso.nome_modulo, nome_pagina, IF(nome_pagina LIKE '/main%', TRUE, FALSE) AS main, IF(nome_pagina LIKE '/test%', TRUE, FALSE) AS test
FROM paginas_acesso
LEFT JOIN tipos_acesso ON tipo_acesso=tipos_acesso.id
WHERE tipo_acesso=40
ORDER BY nome_pagina ASC
```

The result is this:

```
id  tipo_acesso nome_modulo        nome_pagina          main test
11     40          teste      /main/teste/teste.php      1    0
10     40          teste      /test/teste/teste.php      0    1
```

But i want to ignore "/main" and "/test" in the columns "nome_pagina" and show only 1 row.

Something like this:

```
id  tipo_acesso nome_modulo   nome_pagina     main test
11     40          teste    /teste/teste.php   1    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give the result you want:

```
SELECT      MAX(paginas_acesso.id) id
,           MAX(tipo_acesso) tipo_acesso
,           MAX(tipos_acesso.nome_modulo) nome_modulo
,           SUBSTRING(nome_pagina, 6, LEN(nome_pagina) - 5) nome_pagina
,           MAX(IF(nome_pagina LIKE '/main%', TRUE, FALSE)) AS main
,           MAX(IF(nome_pagina LIKE '/test%', TRUE, FALSE)) AS test
FROM        paginas_acesso
LEFT JOIN   tipos_acesso 
        ON  tipo_acesso = tipos_acesso.id
WHERE       tipo_acesso = 40
GROUP BY    SUBSTRING(nome_pagina, 6, LEN(nome_pagina) - 5) nome_pagina
ORDER BY    SUBSTRING(nome_pagina, 6, LEN(nome_pagina) - 5) ASC
```

By the way, it's good practice to use table aliases.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN nome_pagina LIKE '/main/%' THEN substr(nome_pagina, 7)
             WHEN nome_pagina LIKE '/test/%' THEN substr(nome_pagina, 7)
             ELSE nome_pagina
        END)
```